# iPhone 5s speaks the words I type when I text

Tags: ios, keyboard, iphone, text-to-speech, speech

My iPhone 5s speaks the words I type while texting.  How do I stop iPhone 5s from speaking the words I type when texting?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech and disable the options.

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Speech -> Typing feedback`.

Turn off `Characters` and `Speak Auto-text`.

Comment: How does this differ or improve previous answers?

Answer (score -3):

Go to Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech → Typing Feedback and disable Speak Auto-text

Comment: This should've been an edit or comment to the existing answer from 2 years ago, not a new answer that says the exact same thing.